# Android Studio can't change button's colors of AlertDialog JAVA

Tags: android-studio, android-alertdialog

I can't change the text colors of the buttons, I tried every solution found on stackoverflow but nothing.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;

AlertDialog.Builder doubleDishConfirm = new AlertDialog.Builder(AggiungiPiattoAttivity.this, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);

doubleDishConfirm.setPositiveButton( ... ) 
doubleDishConfirm.setNegativeButton( ... )

doubleDishConfirm.show();
```

My MyAlertDialogStyle (in the themes.xml) is:

```
<style name="MyAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <!--<item name="android:buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@android:color/black</item> -->
    <!-- Used for the title and text -->
    <item name="android:negativeButtonText">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
    <!-- Used for the background -->
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

there are comments with other tests I have done, I tried also colorAceent but nothing.

it changes the color of the background, of the writings "try1" and "try2" but the writings of the buttons become invisible.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the item **textColor** in your themes.xml file with the following:

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/tab_background_light_pink</item>
```

If this still doesn't work, you can
try using an `onShowListener` on your `AlertDialog` and then calling `setTextColor`

For example:

```
dialog.setOnShowListener( new OnShowListener() {
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface arg0) {
        dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.(//id of your button)).setTextColor(//whichever color you want);
    }
});
```

Comment: for the first point: I have not styles.xml but themes.xml, I tried using that there but it gives me error, anyway it was like this in colors.xml.

for the second one: dialog can't fina  method called setOnShowListener, it says: Cannot resolve method 'setOnShowListener' in 'DialogInterface'

Comment: Hi, don't put `dialog.setOnShowListener`; by `dialog` I meant the name of your `AlertDialog` i.e. `doubleDishConfirm`. Also, for the first error, try using textColor instead and see what happens.

Comment: yeah I was using my dialog name. I create the dialog and then I do dialog.SetOnShowListener but there isn't this method for the dialog...

Comment: Hi, I went back and checked your code and noticed you have created a builder, but have not actually created your AlertDialog. Also, you have to call .create() on your AlertDialog builder. Call .show() on your actual AlertDialog.